# Toggling visibility of icon when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hamburger-menu

## Problem

I have a dropdown menu that toggles between a hamburger menu and a cross icon when the navigation opens and closes. However, if a user opens the menu, then resizes the window and the window width is still less than 768px (still open), it shows both the icons stacked on top of each other when it only should show the cross.

On a side note, I'm looking to just simplify the complexity of this Javascript snippet. I'm not sure that adding and removing a class of `is-visible` was the correct/best approach.

## JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bdmebsu8/

### scripts.js

```
$(function(){

    // Window size
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $(".icon-cross").hide();
        $(".icon-menu").addClass("is-visible");
        $(".icon-menu").show();
    } else {
        $(".icon-menu").hide();
        $(".icon-menu").removeClass("is-visible");
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(this).innerWidth();
        if (w > 768) {
            $(".nav__list--dropdown").hide();
            $(".icon-cross").hide();
            $(".icon-menu").hide();
            $(".icon-cross").removeClass("is-visible");
            $(".icon-menu").removeClass("is-visible");
        } else {
            $(".icon-cross").hide();
            $(".icon-menu").show();
            $(".icon-menu").addClass("is-visible");
        }
    });

    // Dropdown menu
    $(".nav__menu").on("click", function(){
        $(".is-hidden").slideToggle("slow");

        var menuVisible = $(".icon-menu").hasClass("is-visible")

        if (menuVisible) {
            $(".icon-menu").removeClass("is-visible");
            $(".icon-menu").hide();
            $(".icon-cross").addClass("is-visible");
            $(".icon-cross").show();
        } else {
            $(".icon-cross").removeClass("is-visible");
            $(".icon-cross").hide();
            $(".icon-menu").addClass("is-visible");
            $(".icon-menu").show();
        }
    });
});
```

### index.html

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <ul class="nav__list--dropdown is-hidden">
                    <a href="#services" class="nav__item" target="_blank"><li class="item--services--dropdown">Services</li></a>
                    <a href="#projects" class="nav__item" target="_blank"><li class="item--projects--dropdown">Projects</li></a>
                    <a href="#teaching" class="nav__item" target="_blank"><li class="item--teaching--dropdown">Teaching</li></a>
                    <a href="https://medium.com/@onlyandrewn" class="nav__item" target="_blank"><li class="item--blog--dropdown">Blog</li></a>
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav__item" target="_blank"><li class="item--contact--dropdown">Contact</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>

<div class="nav__menu">
                    <img src="src/img/sm-menu.png" class="icon-menu" alt="Open Menu">
                    <img src="src/img/cross-dark.png" class="icon-cross" alt="Close Menu">
                </div>
```

Comment: I prefer using classes instead of media queries for stuff like this. I do think you can remove a lot of duplicate code if you put the  show/hide/class stuff inside a function. There's even conflicting code: if ($(window).width() <= 768) $(".icon-cross").hide(); but in resize you hide it if w > 768.

Comment: @yezzz Can you elaborate more with a code snippet

Comment: sure.... I'll post it as an answer for clarity

Comment: Can you put your code + css on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that

Comment: First: do you intend to use .is-visible class? As is it only has a z-index style... which is later overridden by .icon-menu, .icon-cross. Second: I'm not seeing the icons stacked, but I do see some logic issues. What you want: if width < 768 only show icon-cross, if width >= 768 only show .icon-menu... is that correct?

Comment: @yezzz I'm not particularly attached to `is-visible`. Yes, you are correct with the logic, I'm trying to do.

Comment: you could also do var w=($(window).width() > 768). It will be true or false. Then look at using w inside $.toggle and $.toggleClass ... they can use true/false.

Comment: @yezzz Can you update your snippet below. Thanks!

Comment: In what way do you mean? With the suggestions above?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do to simplify your script:

```
$(function(){
    function updateMenu(){

        // all logic in here for checking width and show/hide/set classes

    }

    updateMenu();  // runs on doc ready

    $(window).on("resize", updateMenu);
}
```

Comment: Added a link to my JSFiddle above